# Can a crewed capsule land safely if its launch escape tower does not separate?

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, saturn-v, launch-escape-system, orion-spacecraft

Apollo, Soyuz and Orion have used, are using or will use launch escape towers. If it is not needed, it must separate during flight. What if it does not separate? I suppose that the spacecraft would drop its upper stage and land. But these spacecrafts use parachutes to land. Isn't the launch escape tower in their way? And is it safe to land with the added mass of the escape launch tower?

Comment: The answer is no (can't land), but I am stumped for a reference.

Comment: Plasma + solid fuel booster.  What could go wrong ?

Comment: For Apollo, there would have been no mission while the escape tower remained in place, because it would prevent docking with the LM. There would also be no safe landing while the escape tower was in place because the parachutes could not be exposed.

Comment: This is a really interesting question. I think the most important point is the pyros that jettison major components (like the escape system) use very simple, reliable and redundant systems. (Can't find any reliability information though.  I haven't heard of explosive bolts etc. ever failing to separate in manned spaceflight.)

Comment: The redundant explosives on the bolts holding the shuttle stack to the pad failed on one mission. But I agree, I suspect the reason that this failure wasn't in the Apollo flight rules is that it was deemed non credible.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've read somewhere I cannot source now, that explosive bolts are extremely reliable. A company bragging about having used 10,000 explosive bolts in space all without any malfunction. But I imagine there could be a software error or a communication failure that fails a few of them. Does the launch escape tower introduce a danger as much as it is supposed to alleviate one? Compared to the Dragon's towerless launch escape system, the same as its landing system. Btw, will CST-100 use a tower launch escape system too?

Comment: CST-100 does not have a tower http://www.universetoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/MTF10-0014-05.jpg  It uses a pusher abort system http://www.americaspace.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/CST100-capsule.jpg

Comment: @OrganicMarble I wonder if a pusher abort system at the bottom of the service module is vulnerable to an exploding Centaur upper stage. Hydrogen explodes much faster than kerosene and the Dragon has its Draco engines much higher up.

Answer (score 1):

That'd no doubt interfere with the reentry, and the deployments of the parachutes. I suspect they'd call an abort slightly after the failure and maybe actually use the tower to escape, but I'm guessing there. Perhaps it'd be risky to activate it if didn't get jettisoned correctly, who knows how it is remaining attached..

Details on redundancy jettison operations from apollo sim: http://nassp.sourceforge.net/wiki/Launch_Escape_System

And links at the bottom of that page to official docs.

Comment: Apollo mission rules (https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a17/A17MissRules.pdf) p. 123 paragraph H don't list failure of LES to separate as an abort recommendation.

Comment: So what do they do then, carry it to the moon and back? How do they dock with the lem?

Comment: Beats me!  I could not find any reference to this failure mode.

Comment: If you can get into orbit, a contingency EVA is a potential option to get it loose.  Sounds hairy though.

Comment: Calling an abort after the escape system failed to jettison would probably be a mistake - because they wouldn't be able to use the parachutes! I think @pericynthion is right, they would have to get safely into orbit then devise a way to separate the escape system and any shrouds manually, to free the rest of the spacecraft.

Comment: The LES was pretty heavy, I suspect a significant performance impact would be included with all the other issues.

Comment: If LES didn't separate I suspect they could still make orbit, using more fuel from the 3rd stage than usual, thus making translunar flight difficult or impossible. If I were running the show I'd abort the mission and try a very cautious EVA to see how the LES could be detached before reentry.